# react native doesn't fill up window on ios (mobile)

Tags: react-native

My **react-native** project doesn't fill up the screen and everything looks "too big" only on IOS mobile version. (*there are 2 black bars to the top and bottom of the content*)

Any help would be great. Thanks!

The project was migrated to  `react-native: ^0.60.3,`

```
 //App.tsx 
    render (<View style={{flex: 1}} />)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Try removing one '{'? Otherwise try posting minimal, working example.

Comment: did you implement `<SafeAreaView />`?

Comment: @kenmistry, no I didn't. So,  I resolved this issue by adding  LauchScreen.storyboard.  [click](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7507)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was resolved by adding a launch screen file `LauchScreen.storyboard`. See this topic [Click](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7507)